# Rendered formatting of if statements in templates

Tags: php, if-statement

Here's my problem. My code looks like this:

```
<ul class="nav pull-right">
<?php if (!logged_in()) : ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>login"><i class="icon-off"></i> Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>register"><i class="icon-user"></i> Register</a></li>
<?php else : ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>logout"><i class="icon-user"></i> Logout</a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

However, when I view-source in Chrome, the code is all over the place:

```
<ul class="nav pull-right">
                                                    <li><a href="http://localhost/logout"><i class="icon-user"></i> Logout</a></li>
                                            </ul>
```

How can I reorganise my syntax so the source looks like this?

```
<ul class="nav pull-right">
    <li><a href="http://localhost/logout"><i class="icon-user"></i> Logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Unless you're OCD, why bother?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every carriage-return after a closing PHP Tag is not returned to the output buffer. You have to add some extra lines to your code like this:

```
<ul class="nav pull-right">
<?php if (!logged_in()) : echo "\n";  ?>

    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>login"><i class="icon-off"></i> Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>register"><i class="icon-user"></i> Register</a>      
</li>
<?php else : ?>

    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>logout"><i class="icon-user"></i> Logout</a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

You may want to have a look at [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) which is a templating system. It also has functions to remove all spaces which is sometimes very handy.

Comment: I will admit that Twig is very nice, but would not recommend it just for this purpose.  What matters more, your PHP source code or your HTML output's source code? I guarantee you will be looking at the PHP code much more, better to make it readable.

Answer (score 1):

Source code formatting (with a few exceptions) doesn't matter to the browser, CSS, Javascript, whatever. It's mostly vanity, and worrying about it will always give you headaches.

I suggest using the [`Tidy`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) class. Example:

```
$output = "{YOUR FINAL OUTPUT STRING}";
$tidy = new Tidy;
$config = array(
    'indent'              => true,
    'literal-attributes'  => true,
    'wrap'                => 120
);
$tidy->parseString($output, $config, 'utf8');
$tidy->cleanRepair();
echo $tidy;
```